# Publish/Subscribe/Request for exchange of big, complex, and confidential data?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, publish-subscribe

I am working on a project where a website needs to exchange complex and confidential (and thus encrypted) data with other systems. The data includes personal information, technical drawings, public documents etc.

We would prefer to avoid the Request-Reply pattern to the dependent systems (and there are a LOT of them), as that would create an awful lot of empty traffic.

On the other hand, I am not sure that a pure Publisher/Subscriber pattern would be apropriate -- mainly because of the complex and bulky nature of the data to be exchanged.

For that reason we have discussed the possibility of a "publish/subscribe/request" solution. The Publish/Subscribe part would be to publish a message to the dependent systems, that something is ready for pickup. The actual content is then picked up by old-school Request-Reply action.

How does this sound to you??

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: So, the subscribers poll the central message store to see if there is a message for themselves? And then if there is one, they request it?

Comment: @henginy, No the subscriber receives a message from the store, that something can be picked up. This way all empty polls can be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the systems are always online, it sounds **good**.

You might want to look at [***PubSubHubbub***](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) because:
1. Don't solve a problem that has already been solved 2. It is scalable and represents a good separation of concern.

It involves 3 parties:

1. Publishers (who publish stuff)
2. Subscribers (who are interested in certain publications)
3. Hubs (who mediate and get rid of 'polling')

It works in the  following way:

1. A subscriber, registers their interest in a URL with a Hub and provides a callback URL.
2. A publisher, notifies the hub when publishing content.
3. A hub fetches the 'delta' and pushes it to interested subscribers.

The protocol itself is an extension to Atom, but it seems to fit your requirement, e.g. the new Atom 'content' could be an item containing URLs to newly published documents (which can then be downloaded separately).

New/modified documents => new/modified items in feed containing URLs to fetch them => Hub => Subscribers => Pull documents from Publisher

Comment: Like I just wrote to Aron: I assumed that my described solution should support off-line subscribers. How does it not? :-) Morten

Comment: So, in the design you describe, what happens to the publish notifications if the subscriber is off? I guess the plan is that: The publisher retries the failed notification every so often? This is pretty much the same as 'polling' in reverse. So the advantage of not having to poll is gone, right? So unless the services involved are usually all 'up', the approach loses its advantage.

Comment: Exactly :-) All services should usually up (95+ percent). But I cannot assume 100 percent.

Comment: Then it's a reasonable design. You retry if a message fails, and because usually services are up, failures are not frequent, so retries are okay. Everything is serene and beautiful, IMO. So anyway, my answer was only meant to suggest a reasonably standard way of doing what you do, instead of designing from the ground up. The fact that the services involved are always online was why I felt it best fits your requirement.

Comment: Aaron's suggestion, like he mentioned was for "messages to PCs that are turned off for the night/weekend", and he is right. If that happens, then the whole 'push not poll' idea breaks down.

Comment: We are not talking server-to-pc, but server-to-server communication.

Comment: Yes we are talking about server-server. This is what I assumed when I wrote my answer. This is why I think (and I wrote in my answer) that the design you plan on is good. This is why I suggested PubSubHubbub, because it appears to 'fit' your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a great experience about this, but a messaging queue should help you accomplish what you need. I am using such a system while managing publishing data to multiple front end clients from a backend.

If the client is off, the data is not consumed and the server receives no acknowledgement of data being reveived. Once the client comes back online he consumes the data and remains listening for more messages onve the queue is clear. And ofc the publisher receives a ack for data being consumed. In this way we can identify and notify people who have problems at the receiving end as a bonus. Could this do it in your case?

Answer (score 1):

This approach works if the dependent systems are always online - you can't send messages to PCs that are turned off for the night/weekend.

So if the clients are servers that run 24/7, this works. Otherwise, try this approach:

1. Let clients register themselves
2. When new documents come in, add an entry "client X needs to see this" in your database
3. When clients connect, send them all the entries.
4. When clients successfully downloaded a document, delete the "client X needs to see this" entry. That keeps the work table small.

This has several advantages:

1. Clients don't need to run 24/7
2. The flag is only removed after the client has seen the document (so no updates can be lost).
3. You have one place where you can see which client never pulls it's documents. A simple `select client, count(*) group by client having count(*) > 10` tells you about problems.
4. Most clients will fetch their data timely, so the work table will stay small. That means there is little overhead when you have to collect the "what's now" data.

**EDIT** The problem with off-line subscribers is that they don't know what they're missing. So the sending side needs to keep track of the failed push/pull requests. Which means you must implement my suggested pseudo-code to make sure broken connections can be resumed.

Comment: @Aron, I assumed that my described solution should support off-line subscribers. How does it not? :-) Morten